# How to retrieve data from .xls file and use them in three.js 3D model animation?

Tags: javascript, 3d, xls

I developed a dynamic 3D cube with three.js that rotate and translate to visualize data coming from accelerometer and gyroscope.
I initially made the 3D cube rotate and translate using a randomly generate data.
Click on the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samiarja/cezshq8f/1/)  to see the example I created.

I have two problem which I am struggling to solve and I tried multiple ways to solve but it never worked as intended:

**Problem1:**

I want to parse data from .xls which contains sample data from accelerometer and gyroscope and feed to the 3D cube so I can move according the value given.
Basically replacing the code below

```
objects.forEach((obj) => {
obj.rotation.x = speed+1;
obj.rotation.y = speed+2;
obj.rotation.z = speed+34;
obj.position.x = speed+1;
obj.position.y = speed+2;
obj.position.z = speed+2;
});
```

with a function that parse and iterate through the actual acc and gyro data from the .xls data. Something like that:

```
objects.forEach((obj) => {
obj.rotation.x = Gyro_X;
obj.rotation.y = Gyro_Y;
obj.rotation.z = Gyro_Z;
obj.position.x = Accelero_X;
obj.position.y = Accelero_Y;
obj.position.z = Accelero_Z;
});
```

I tried to convert the .xls to .json but the process needs to parse all the data in the file and then I can use it in the 3D cube. This is not feasable because I need to wait a while until all the file is fetched before feeding into the 3D model. I want to be able to loop through the value sequentially to see the 3D cube rotate and translate accordingly.

The data structure are shown below:
[image]

this is how I parsed the data from the .xls file using [read-excel-file](https://github.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file)

```
<script>
            var input = document.getElementById('input')

            input.addEventListener('change', function() {
              readXlsxFile(input.files[0], { dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YY' }).then(function(data) {
                // `data` is an array of rows
                // each row being an array of cells.
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)

              }, function (error) {
                console.error(error)
                alert("Error while parsing Excel file. See console output for the error stack trace.")
              })
            })
        </script>
```

**Problem2:**

I want to visualize the accelerometer and gyroscope on the canvas like shown below:

[image]

I got answer to my problem in a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319696/how-to-display-coordinate-value-on-the-top-of-a-3d-cube-three-js/65352447#65352447) I posted. but when I tried to integrated the solution into my code like shown below, it didn't work as it didn't show any information on the canvas as expected. I think I am not placing the .innerHtml in the right position or possibly I missed some other curial steps.

```
objects.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.rotation.x = speed+1;
      obj.rotation.y = speed+2;
      obj.rotation.z = speed+34;
      obj.position.x = speed+1;
      obj.position.y = speed+2;
      obj.position.z = speed+2;
      
      console.log(obj.position.y);
    });
   
    accelPanel.innerHtml = "Accelerometer:<br>X: " + obj.rotation.x + "<br>Y: " + obj.rotation.y + "<br>Z: " + obj.rotation.z;
```

I would appreciate if there is a solution to my problems, even a hint would help in getting through these issues. That would be much appreciated as I was stuck for a while on these problems.

Comment: So can we assume that you already have the excel data parsed and ready in an array or something? Because in that case all you need to do is keep a row counter variable and increase it in your render function, then read the respective row data.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for pointing this out. I edited my post. I used read-excel-file to parse my excel file which convert it to json string. But I has to parse all the data then you can do other things which is not a good option for me if I want to run the code and see the motion of the 3D cube faster

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue is. If reading the Excel file takes some time, you simply cannot show the cube moving according to its data before that, you'll have to wait. Also, please stick to a single problem per question and remove all irrelevant code / info.

Comment: I wondering if there is another way of parsing the excel file one by one and instead of everything at once (like a real-time system). I will try to edit the question as much as I can, but these are the problems I am facing and I would like to have a solution for them :(

Comment: I still haven't got an answer for that. Any help please?